# SELECT query with selecting multiple columns where one column should be distinct mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a table containing `PRTL_BusRoute` which refers to `ID` of various zones and `AreaID` as the `ID's` areas coming under each zone.

```
**ID**   **BustrouteID**   **AreaID**

    0          1             3
    1          1             5
    1          1             6
    2          2             5
    3          2             6    
    4          2             8
    5          3             9
    6          3             12
    7          4             1
    8          4             8
    9          4             11
```

The names of Bus routes are stored in `tbl_BusRoute` and areas are stored in `dbo.GEN_Area`.I need to display like this:

```
 Zonename1
    Areas coming under this zone in a list

 Zonename2
    Areas coming under this zone in a list
 ........
```

My php code is like this:

```
$area = '';                                                               
$getbus = mssql_query("SELECT BusRouteID,AreaID  FROM dbo.Acc_BusRouteDetail");
       while($data_getbus = mssql_fetch_row($getbus)){ 
           $getZone = mssql_query("SELECT Busroute FROM PRTL_BusRoute 
           WHERE BusRouteID = '$data_getbus[0]'");  
           while($data_getZone = mssql_fetch_row($getZone)){
                     $zone_name =  "<h4>".$data_getZone[0]."</h4>"; 
                     }  
       $getArea = mssql_query("SELECT AreaName_1 FROM dbo.GEN_Area 
          WHERE AreaID = '$data_getbus[1]'  ORDER BY AreaName_1");
       while($data_getArea = mssql_fetch_row($getArea)){
           $area .= $data_getArea[0]."</br>";
       }
       echo $zone_name."<br/>".$area."<br/>";
   }
```

The output is coming like this:

```
ZoneName1
      Areaname1

   ZoneName1
      AreaName1
      AreaName2

   ZoneName1
      AreaName1
      Areaname2
      AreaName3

   ZoneName2
     Areaname1

   ZoneName2
     Areaname1
     Areaname2 so on
```

I would like to know if possible how can I select distinct busroutes and all the areas coming under it. I run out of logic how to select single route ID and then select all the areas coming under it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the SQL query a little to get all the data at once, and loop and print the area each time, while just printing the bus route if it changed since the last row. Something like this (untested) code;

```
$last_route = '';
$getbus = mssql_query("SELECT br.BusRoute,a.AreaName_1 FROM dbo.Acc_BusRouteDetail brd JOIN dbo.PRTL_BusRoute br ON br.busrouteid = brd.busrouteid JOIN dbo.GEN_Area a ON a.areaid = brd.areaid ORDER BY br.busroute, a.areaname_1");
while($data_getbus = mssql_fetch_array($getbus)){ 
   if($last_route != $data_getbus['BusRoute']) {
      $last_route = $data_getbus['BusRoute'];
      echo '<h4>'.$last_route.'</h4>';
   }
   echo '<br/>'.$data_getbus['AreaName_1'].'</br>';
}
```

Comment: @Techy What is the problem with it? If you cut'n'paste the SQL query to management studio, does it give any error?

Comment: The result is not displaying.The controller is not going inside the while loop.I have tested the sql query inside sqlStudio,its showing the result.In the web page no result is shown

Comment: @Techy Fixed the loop, I was erroneously using $getbus instead of $data_getbus.